# RNFirebase core module was not found natively on Android, ensure you have correctly added the RNFirebase and Firebase gradle dependencies

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have this strange error for a hours and I can't fix it. I have all dependencies that I need.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNLLZ.png)

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
    implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-iap')
    implementation project(':react-native-amplitude-analytics')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you have included this line in MainApplication.java

```
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
```

and

```
 @Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new RNFirebasePackage(), <----- this
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I already fixed it. It was a problem with an android studio or something like this

Comment: @Davydoff not a massively helpful reply ha. What was "the problem with an android studio or something"?

Comment: However the above answer did work. I'd been avoiding doing that because I was of the belief that you didn't need to do that if you were using RN60